# extracting list from result set

Tags: java, list, jdbc, resultset

I have a query running and I have the result in a `ResultSet`. I am trying to parse the result set to extract the information to a list.

```java
static List<Person> parsePeople(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Offer>();
    while(rs.next()) {
        people.add(parsePerson(rs));
    }
    return people;
}

static Person parsePerson(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    Person p= new Person();
    p.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));      
    p.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));

    //Extracting the list for number of siblings gives an error

    //Tried the below
     List<Integer>siblings= (List<Integer>) rs.getObject("siblings",ArrayList.class); //Fail
        
    return p;
}

Class Person{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    List<Integer> numberOfSiblings;
}
```

How to extract the list from the result set?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that includes the query and table structure you're querying, example data, and the problem your current code has with extracting the information you want.

Comment: *//Tried the below* Why? All you need is `return p;`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parse the whole array-list from resultset at once. you have to iterate through the resultset and put each record in your arraylist one by one. for example,

```
while(resultset.next()) {
    siblings.add(new person(resultset.getString("firstName"), resultset.getString("lastName")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The jdbc won't allow the SQL type of `"siblings"` to be returned as an ArrayList java type. You should consult the documentation for your JDBC's valid return types for `"siblings"`. For example this is [Microsoft's documentation for the JDBC 4.0 on SQL server 2016's default return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types?view=sql-server-2016)

Assuming siblings is a numeric type, you could do:

```
 Integer siblings = rs.getObject("siblings", Integer.class);
```